# Sprite doesn't change material or picture

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites

I am quite new to unity and currenty I'm practicing with a 2D topdown game.

I created a tile map with "tiled", imported it in Unity with "TiledToUnity" and changed some things like player movement, camera and so on.

Now I wanted to create collectible coins. So I created a new 2D Sprite and added the picture of the coin I had to it. But the picture of the coin did not change. I tried the same with adding a material with the coin as picture but it did not work out either.

To check if the object is even there I added a collide box to the coin and my player body did indeed collide.

What did I do wrong while adding a picture to the sprite?

Thanks in advance!

(Sorry fotgot the pictures. )
-- Edit--

[image: Added Emission]
[image: yellow color where transparency should be.]

Comment: Do you have code or images of your work space so we can see what you are doing/trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, forgot them.

Comment: hmm maybe coin is behind of the map! in Sprite Renderer there is option as order in layer , change it to bigger number than 1 like 2.

Comment: Already tried that. I also created a new layer for the coins and hid the default layer with the map and player but i still did not see the material.

Comment: I found something that might help. I changed the Emission of the material inside the obejct inspector and added the picture of the coin there. Now i see coin image, but the transparent part of it now has a yellow-ish color. Added pictured to my main post.

Comment: Ok, I also fixed that problem. I just had to change the shader of the material to Sprite -> Default and the weird yellow background is gone. The colors are still quite strrange but I changed the tint so it still looks quite good.

Comment: @MarcelM. If you have found your own solution, consider post it as answer to your own question. Yes, in Stack Exchange you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the Shader of the material to Sprite -> Default the problem was fixed.

Comment: Are you using lighting in your scene? If not, you might want to use a simpler shader than the PBR "Standard" - it will be more lightweight to render and won't require hacks like doubling-up a texture in the emissive channel. The default Sprite material should be all you need.

Comment: As stated in a comment under my question I did already change that.